# How do you get full paths of all files in a directory in Go?

Tags: go

I am using Go to iterate over all the files in a directory. This is how I am doing it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    printFiles(".")
}

func printFiles(dir string) {
    fileInfos, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in accessing directory:", err)
    }

    for _, file := range fileInfos {
        fmt.Printf("%T: %+v\n", file, file)
    }
}
```

When I run this code, this is the output I get:

```
*os.fileStat: &{name:main.go sys:{FileAttributes:32 CreationTime:{LowDateTime:2993982878 HighDateTime:30613689} LastAccessTime:{LowDateTime:2993982878 HighDateTime:30613689} LastWriteTime:{LowDateTime:4004986069 HighDateTime:30613714} FileSizeHigh:0 FileSizeLow:320} pipe:false Mutex:{state:0 sema:0} path:C:\Users\Prakhar.Mishra\go\src\mistdatafilter\main.go vol:0 idxhi:0 idxlo:0}
```

I can see a property named **path**, but I can't access it (due to small case initial, I suppose?). Can anyone please tell me how to get full file path of all the files in a given folder?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to see a full path, you should start with a full path. `.` is a relative path.

You can get the working path with [os.Getwd](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getwd)

```
path, err := os.Getwd()
// handle err
printFiles(path)
```

The rest is simply appending the file name to the directory path. You should use the [`path/filepath`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) package for that:

```
for _, file := range fileInfos {
    fmt.Println(filepath.Join(path, file.Name())
}
```

Comment: what if you're trying to get  the directory of a file which is the target of a symbolic link in another folder? In this case `os.Lstat(filepath.Join(currentDir, target))` will fail

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the [filepath.Abs](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Abs) method from the standard library

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

files, _ = os.ReadDir(dir)
path, _ := filepath.Abs(dir)
for _, file := range files {
    fmt.Println(filepath.Join(path, file.Name())
}
```

Comment: ioutil.ReadDir() is deprecated since Go 1.16, you should use os.ReadDir() instead

Answer (score 1):

You already have the directory path simply append them to the file name something like:

```
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dirPath)
check(err)

for _, file := range files {
    fmt.Println(dirPath + file.Name())
}
```

Comment: ioutil.ReadDir(dirPath) is deprecated it's os.ReadDir() now